# ImportError: No module named 'scrapy'

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I am fairly new to Python using 3.6 on Windows.

I have installed Scrapy using Anaconda:

```
> C:\Users\user.name>conda install scrapy Fetching package metadata
> ............. Solving package specifications: .
> 
> # All requested packages already installed.
> # packages in environment at C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:
> # scrapy                    1.3.3                    py36_0
```

However, when I try to import it n the Python IDE I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'scrapy'
```

I also tried with pip which confirmed that all requirements are satisfied. I have  searched for an answer and think this may be because I have installed it for one interpreter/environment and am trying to use it in another.

Although, I am not sure if this is correct, or how to tackle it. This is the first time I have used Anaconda (previously I'd just been using PyCharm and pip) so I'm going to spend some time today getting to grips with it, but would appreciate if anyone was able to point me in the right direction!

Comment: why not using `pip`?

Comment: Are you certain your Python IDE is running the python interpreter from the conda environment, and not the global one?

Comment: Try to create new [virtual environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) in conda and install scrapy there, and don't forget to [activate](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate) your environment.

Comment: @NilsWerner I'm not, I suspect that might be my problem actually. How can I get my IDE (and PyCharm?) to run from the conda environment?

Comment: @Maverick I have 3 years of programming experience and I tried installing Scrapy on Windows 10 ... I tried that for about 4 days but in vain ... then I finally installed Ubuntu in VMWare. I suggest you the same

Comment: Thanks @Umair, I managed to get it installed but am I will give Ubuntu a go out of curiosity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a new [virtual environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) in conda and install scrapy there, and don't forget to [activate](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate) your environment.
In PyCharm you can [specify](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html#d34818e36) what environment you want to use for a project in Settings/YourProject/Project Interpreter.

Comment: Thanks vold. I've created the snowflaves env - how can I install scrapy within it?

Comment: Okay. I activated snowflakes and then run conda insall scrapy - that's it?

Comment: Well, you better select some scrapy related name - scrapyvenv for example. After you create an environment you need to choose him for your project interpreter in PyCharm. You work in PyCharm right? Try conda install -c conda-forge scrapy.

Comment: Or you can manually select scrapy in PyCharm: File | Settings | Project Interpreter [Available packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/available-packages.html)

Comment: Thanks I got there in the end! - Appreciate your help!